# setting up serverless.yml file to use a specific aws profile

Tags: serverless-framework

Instead of running `sls deploy --aws-profile <name>`, is there a way to configure the `serverless.yml` file to just contain this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `provider` section:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  profile: aws-profile-name
```